# GWT UiBinder dynamic internationalization

Tags: gwt, internationalization

I'd like to use dynamic internationalization in my GWT app, with a `Dictionary` class approach.

Can I use it with uiBinder like this?

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
    <span>{Dictionary.getDictionary("locale").get("hello_world_key")}</span>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

(Flex mxml files work like this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, UiBinder only supports calling zero-arg non-static methods or importing static fields.

You'd have to *hide* the dictionary behind a class or interface to be able to do something like `{myDictionary.hello_world_key}`.

IMO, if you do want to use dynamic I18N, use an interface similar to `com.google.gwt.i18N.shared.Constants` and make your own generator so that `String hello_world_key();` maps to `get("hello_world_key")` on a `Dictionary` instance. Your code will read better and become more maintainable.